# How to define and deliver Fiori rolese/launchpads for own SAPUI5 apps?

Tags: sap-fiori

Assumptions:

- Multiple SAPUI5 apps are build
- they should be deliverable (via SAP transport system, potentially over transport files) into different clients
- technical steps to create roles and launchpads are known
- a SAP namespace is registered and available

Question:

- Is there any guide to design the launchpads/roles for these apps especially to make it deliverable to different customers?

Answer (score 1):

There are guidelines in the [FLP documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/f9/b0ccce0766442ca8237eee23494f17/content.htm?frameset=/en/ef/1eb51b768d42708e3f1de8ec0d5139/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/e4/843b8c3d05411c83f58033bac7f072/plain.htm&node_id=87&show_children=false). 
This documentation describes how to create your own Fiori Launchpad content, such as catalogs, groups, and so on. Delivery however differs depending on whether its ABAP on premise, HCP, the delivery channel, and so on.

Comment: It is about delivering Apps to customers (premise and over transports).